# WSO API manager v3 - error message when creating documents for API in publisher

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I try to create documents for published API in WSO2 APIM publisher, but I receive error message below. Could somebody help with this?

The steps I followed are:

1. I fill in the form for document Name: xxxxx, Summary: xxxxx, type: How To, Source: Inline
2. Click on Add Document
3. Add Content

   ```
   FormattedMessage is not defined     

   "ReferenceError: FormattedMessage is not defined
       at https://xxxx:9443/publisher/site/public/dist/8.bundle.js:1:315001
       at na (https://xxxx:9443/publisher/site/public/dist/index.bundle.js:14:58550)
       at Ia (https://xxxx:9443/publisher/site/public/dist/index.bundle.js:14:65871)
       at Xu (https://xxxx:9443/publisher/site/public/dist/index.bundle.js:14:104381)
       at ml (https://xxxx:9443/publisher/site/public/dist/index.bundle.js:14:88984)
       at hl (https://xxxx:9443/publisher/site/public/dist/index.bundle.js:14:88909)
       at rl (https://xxxx:9443/publisher/site/public/dist/index.bundle.js:14:85855)
       at https://xxxx:9443/publisher/site/public/dist/index.bundle.js:14:45068
       at t.unstable_runWithPriority 
       (https://xxxx:9443/publisher/site/public/dist/index.bundle.js:30:3463)
       at zo (https://xxxx:9443/publisher/site/public/dist/index.bundle.js:14:44778)

   in Unknown
   in withRouter()
   in t
   in t
   in div
   in el
   in component
   in t
   in t
   in div
   in div
   in Ru
   in ForwardRef
   in injectIntl(Component)
   in t
   in t
   in Unknown
   in Suspense
   in qt
   in t
   in t
   in div
   in div
   in G
   in ForwardRef
   in $e
   in ForwardRef
   in Unknown
   in Vt
   in Suspense
   in t
   in t
   in t
   in t
   in w
   in IntlProvider
   in M"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same steps you have mentioned in WSO2 API Manager 3.0.0, but I could not reproduce the issue you are mentioning. Can you share a sample inline text content that you are using to further analyse this issue.

Comment: I receive this error message prior to inserting any text to the document.